# mongoose save only saving partial document (strict : false)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created an extra collection to be used as a cache for data for the welcome screen of my app. Every hour I run a set of aggregate queries on my normal collections and create a new object of welcome screen data which I add to my welcomeScreenData collection and only the most recent document in that collection is used on the welcome screen of my app.

As I am using mongoose for my application I have created an empty schema for this cache collection:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var welcomeScreenDataSchema = new Schema({}, { strict : false });

var WelcomeScreenData = mongoose.model('WelcomeScreenData', welcomeScreenDataSchema, 'welcomeScreenData');

module.exports = WelcomeScreenData;
```

The results of my queries are saved to a WelcomeScreenData object:

```
var welcomeScreenData = new WelcomeScreenData({
  featured : results[0],
  popular : results[1],
  new : results[2]
});
console.log(welcomeScreenData);
welcomeScreenData.save(function(error, welcomeScreenData){
  if(error){
    callback(error);
  }else{
    callback();
  }
});
```

When I log out the object I am about to save it contains three arrays (featured, popular and new), which are each an array of objects.

After saving, the database contains the same three arrays, but the 'featured' array contains only objectIds, rather than the full objects. I thought that using `strict : false` would mean that the whole object should be saved in any situation. What could be causing the whole object to not be saved in this case?

The only difference in the way I get the data for the 'featured' array is that they are from the populated part of a [deep populate](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate) query, but at the point of the save isn't everything just javascript objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did seem to be related to the deep populate. After getting the results of the deep populate query, I was extracting the populated part of the results to write to the new collection. I needed to use `toObject()` on the results of the query before extracting the data I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

As per the doc [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict). 'Strict' ensures that values passed to our model constructor that were not specified in our schema do not get saved to the db.

By disabling it you are forcing Mongoose to save even those values which are not part of the Schema. It doesn't deep populate

Comment: Yes, that is why I expect the whole object to be saved - it is all there before the save, and strict is false, so there should be nothing stopping it being saved. The deep populate is just how I get the data in the first place, not involved in the save.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. I thought 'featured' was an array of ObjectIds , sorry, my bad.
yes, you are right. It should have stored correctly without any problem. 
Are you getting correct result in console.log(welcomeScreenData)? 
Have you tried Mixed Type?